# Show that $D_{n+1}=(a+b)D_n-abD_{n-1}$ for all $n\ge 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D_n$ be the determinant of the following n x n matrix.

[image: n x n matrix]

i) Show that $D_{n+1}=(a+b)D_n-abD_{n-1}$ for all $n\ge 2$

ii) If $a \neq b$, find a general formula for $D_n$ in terms of $a$,$b$ and $n$.

iii) If $a = b$, find a general formula for $D_n$ in terms of $a$ and $n$.

Comment: expand along top row.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown i dont see how $D_{n-1}$ can be formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D_n=x^n$ in the recurrence equation to get $$x^n(x-(a+b)+
\frac{ab}{x})=0 \implies x=a, b$$ So $$D_n=A~ a^n + B~ b^n.$$
If $a=b$, then $$D_n=(An+B)a^n$$

Comment: how did you get x = a,b?

Comment: @CXY Roots of $x^2-(a+b)x+ab-0$ are $x=a.b$..

Comment: is there a way to do it with the eigenvalue technique?

Comment: If there are two recurrence relations in  fir two quantities, then eigenvalue method  is applied.